# Laravel Cashier + Can you customize the additonal field for a subscription

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

I have a question while using laravel cashier with stripe, can you customize stripes additional fields to a field that is not supplied by stripe. Like if i wanted to customize stripe table and add my own field is that possible?

Just to test i added a integer field called random_id to the stripe subscription migration, when trying to make a subscription i set the default value to 1 i just to see if it would display in the database and it doesn't so i am wondering how can i achieve this using laravel cashier.

---

paymentcontroller

```
   public function subscribe(Request $request)
    {
        $user = auth()->user();
        $paymentMethod = $request->payment_method;

        $planId = $request->plan;
        $user->newSubscription('main', $planId)->create($paymentMethod, [
            'random_id' => 1,
        ]);

        return response([
            'success_url' => redirect()->intended('/')->getTargetUrl(),
            'message' => 'success'
        ]);
    }
```

---

Payment.blade.php

```
@section('content')


   <select name="plan" class="form-control" id="subscription-plan">
                            @foreach($plans as $key=>$plan)
                                <option value="{{$key}}">{{$plan}}</option>
                            @endforeach
                        </select>

                    <input placeholder="Card Holder" class="form-control" id="card-holder-name" type="text">

                    <!-- Stripe Elements Placeholder -->
                    <div id="card-element"></div>

                    <button class="mt-2 btn btn-sm btn-primary" id="card-button" data-secret="{{ $intent->client_secret }}">
                        Subscribe
                    </button>

@endsection


@section('js')
<script>


       window.addEventListener('load', function() {
            const stripe = Stripe('{{env('STRIPE_KEY')}}');
            const elements = stripe.elements();
            const cardElement = elements.create('card');
            cardElement.mount('#card-element');
            const cardHolderName = document.getElementById('card-holder-name');
            const cardButton = document.getElementById('card-button');
            const clientSecret = cardButton.dataset.secret;
            const plan = document.getElementById('subscription-plan').value;
            cardButton.addEventListener('click', async (e) => {
                const { setupIntent, error } = await stripe.handleCardSetup(
                    clientSecret, cardElement, {
                        payment_method_data: {
                            billing_details: { name: cardHolderName.value }
                        }
                    }
                );
                if (error) {
                    // Display "error.message" to the user...
                } else {
                    // The card has been verified successfully...
                    console.log('handling success', setupIntent.payment_method);
                    axios.post('/subscribe',{
                        payment_method: setupIntent.payment_method,
                        plan : plan
                    }).then((data)=>{
                        location.replace(data.data.success_url)
                    });
                }
            });
        })

</script>
```